# Android Alert Dialog with ActionBar Enabled

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-alertdialog

Is it possible in Android to show a custom `Alert Dialog` in a `Fragment` below the `ActionBar`, having enabled the `ActionBar` Buttons and disabled the below screen for any action (thats what an `Alert Dialog` do).

My need is to enable the `ActionBar` during the `AlertDialog` is opened.

Thanks in advance.